# Why the RegEx is being changed if I add it via interpolation in HTML?

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I'am using this RegEx for password:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z\d!\x22#$%&'()*+,./:;\x3c=\x3e?@[\]^_`{|}~/\\/-])[A-Za-z\d!\x22#$%&'()*+,./:;\x3c=\x3e?@[\]^_`{|}~/\\/-]{8,50}$
```

to allow all the following special characters:

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

It works fine when running the test with [Online regex tester](https://regex101.com/) - here is the String I tested:

```
!Q2\w3e4r#$@!%&*?{}[]^_`|<=>~(dd)&,":;./asQ+-A
```

My issue is when/if I add the RegEx inside the input-field directly in the HTML, then it works fine:

```
<input type="text"  name="password" pattern="^(?=.*[a-zA-Z\d!\x22#$%&'()*+,./:;\x3c=\x3e?@[\]^_`{|}~/\\/-])[A-Za-z\d!\x22#$%&'()*+,./:;\x3c=\x3e?@[\]^_`{|}~/\\/-]{8,50}$" (blur)="onBlur(inputPass.value)" #inputPass>
```

But if I save it in a variable in `*.component.ts`, and then use is it in the view as I'am using it in angular app (interpolation), it's being changed. In other words it change the RegEx which I can see via Chrome Console when expecting the element.

**signin.component.ts:**

```
this.PASS_PATTERN_VIEW = '^(?=.*[a-zA-Z\d!\x22#$%&'()*+,./:;\x3c=\x3e?@[\]^_`{|}~/\\/-])[A-Za-z\d!\x22#$%&'()*+,./:;\x3c=\x3e?@[\]^_`{|}~/\\/-]{8,50}$';
```

**signin.component.html:**

```
<input type="password" name="password" pattern="{{PASS_PATTERN_VIEW}}" (blur)="onBlur(inputPass.value)" #inputPass>
```

Here is what I get as RegEx after running the app which is totally different to my original RegEx:

```
<input type="password" name="password" pattern="^(?=.*[a-zA-Zd!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~/\/-])[A-Za-zd!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~/\/-]{8,50}$" (blur)="onBlur(inputPass.value)" #inputPass>
```

To summarize the RegEx is being changed from:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z\d!\x22#$%&'()*+,./:;\x3c=\x3e?@[\]^_`{|}~/\\/-])[A-Za-z\d!\x22#$%&'()*+,./:;\x3c=\x3e?@[\]^_`{|}~/\\/-]{8,50}$
```

to:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Zd!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~/\/-])[A-Za-zd!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~/\/-]{8,50}$
```

So what should be changed/added to fix these kind of issues/errors?

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is and how the community can help you. You can do all debugging steps by yourself . Try to assign a string to `pattern` directly with escaped `"`. Try to assign it to PASS_PATTERN_VIEW directly. Try to check if `environment.passRegExpView ===` this string.

Comment: I definitely agree with you... was also not easy for me to describe the issue. One thing I can add is the error which Visual Studio Code throws: `[ts] The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.` and `[ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'String' has no compatible call signatures.`

Comment: Where exactly does it throw it? The errors doesn't help if they don't refer to particular line. *I add the RegEx directly in the HTML like* - as I said, you have to escape `"`. Because it is the character that surrounds attr value.

Comment: Done... I have added the missing info regarding the error. Yes, I assume it has to do with escaping `"` - Do you mean the opening and closing double quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there was no answer to my question here and my issue description was not really helpful, I did post [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48640848/how-to-prevent-regex-characters-from-being-changed-after-page-is-rendered) handling the same issue...

The issue is/was fixed... it was actually affecting the double backslashes etc.

RegEx solution for the HTML/View should be:

```
"^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])[A-Za-z\\d!\\x22#$%&'()*+,.:;\\x3c=\\x3e?@[\\]^_`{|}~/\\\\-]{8,50}$"
```

For more information, pls. check [demo](https://regex101.com/r/p3GAW7/2) as mentioned in the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48640848/how-to-prevent-regex-characters-from-being-changed-after-page-is-rendered)