# How to prevent regex characters from being changed after page is rendered?

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript

I'am stuck after searching and trying several tests, but just can't figure out how to fix the following issue.

I use these characters `\x3c`, `\x3e` and `\x22` in a regEx and save is in  a variable in `*.component.ts` but when I use the variable in the markup/HTML, it turns it into `<`, `>` and `"`. the result is that my Pattern doesn't work as expected.

Here is one of test on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/p3GAW7/1) and as you can see it works as it should be:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z\d!\x22#$%&\'()*+,.:;\x3c=\x3e?@[\]^_`{|}~/\\-])[A-Za-z\d!\x22#$%&\'()*+,.:;\x3c=\x3e?@[\]^_`{|}~/\\-]{8,50}$
```

How can I prevent this and keep the characters as they are in the original when the page is rendered? Is it a behavior of TypeScript or JavaScript browser engine or what? Any hint would be great.

Comment: Try doubling the backslashes.

Comment: adding to @WiktorStribiżew , end with /pattern+/g?

Comment: I tried using it as: `/\x3c` and the output is: `\/\x3c` whish wrong. I need just: `\x3c` have been reading the [doc](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) here too.

Comment: @Hey24sheep: Can't figure out what you exactly mean

Comment: To be more specific, here is the whole pattern: `'^(?=.*[a-zA-Z\d!\x22#$%&\'()*+,.:;\x3c=\x3e?@[\]^_`{|}~/\\-])[A-Za-z\d!\x22#$%&\'()*+,.:;\x3c=\x3e?@[\]^_`{|}~/\\-]{8,50}$'`

Comment: @k.vincent update your question with what you are doing, what's the pattern for and what you want, With Code. In js you need to double escape the pattern and end it with +/g that I showed above.

Comment: Why are you down-voting me/my question? I tried to keep the question as simple as it is it order to avoid misunderstanding regarding any further codes etc. Adding the link to my tests, search doc etc. is a sign for not having doing efforts to solve it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: double backslashes did the trick... but the other backslash here: `\x22#$%&\` last one is then being removed and if I try the same there it causes the following error in Visual Studio Code: `[ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'String' has no compatible call signatures.`

Comment: @k.vincent I haven't downvoted you or your question.

Comment: Sorry, your comment is not formatted well, I have no idea what the issue is after you use double escapes.

Comment: @No problem... Your hint did help much. looks good. One thing is still missing is that the RegEx must include at least one Capital letter which is not case now. Here is the new RegEx: `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z\\d!\\x22#$%&\\\'()*+,.:;\\x3c=\\x3e?@[\\]^_`{|}~/\\\\\-])[A-Za-z\\d!\\x22#$%&\\\'()*+,.:;\\x3c=\\x3e?@[\\]^_`{|}~/\\\\\-]{8,50}$`

Comment: After `@`, please use the user name to notify me or someone else of your feedback. Please share a link to regex101 with the regex. I believe all you need is to add `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])` after `^` now.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Sry for that. Used it but somehow went lost. I'll check the hint. Here  is my test [Test](https://regex101.com/r/p3GAW7/1)

Comment: Your current regex makes no sense: the consuming part is also a requirement inside the lookahead. See https://regex101.com/r/p3GAW7/2, I think this is what you need.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: The hint regarding forcing capital letter looks good and works fine. Great. If you don't mind, you can add all you tipps as an answer, os that I can confirm/accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to use double backslashes to introduce literal backslashes into the regex patterns. I.e. if you write `"\x22"` as a string literal, it is in fact a mere `"`. So, to define `\x22` in a string literal, write `"\\x22"`.

Then, you have

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z\d!\x22#$%&\'()*+,.:;\x3c=\x3e?@[\]^_`{|}~/\\-])[A-Za-z\d!\x22#$%&\'()*+,.:;\x3c=\x3e?@[\]^_`{|}~/\\-]{8,50}$
```

The lookahead here is redundant because it requires the same set of chars as is required by the consuming part. The lookahead can be removed, or better replaced with the one you need, `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])`, requiring at least 1 uppercase ASCII letter:

```
^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])[A-Za-z\d!\x22#$%&\'()*+,.:;\x3c=\x3e?@[\]^_`{|}~/\\-]{8,50}$
```

As a string literal:

```
"^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])[A-Za-z\\d!\\x22#$%&'()*+,.:;\\x3c=\\x3e?@[\\]^_`{|}~/\\\\-]{8,50}$"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p3GAW7/2).